# PDO not working when using MONTH() in query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to execute a PDO query, but it returns zero results. But when I run the query in MySQL, then it returns two rows. This issue only occurs when I add `MONTN(column)` in the PDO query.

What I have in PHP is this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM payment WHERE  `user_id` = :userid_53e3d3275e364  AND  MONTH(pay_date) = :monthpaydate_53e3d3275e373  ORDER BY `pay_date` DESC';

$bindings = array ( 'userid_53e3d3275e364' => 8, 
                    'monthpaydate_53e3d3275e373' => 'MONTH(CURDATE())' );


$stmt = $this->db->prepare ( $sql );
$stmt->execute ( $bindings );
$result = $stmt->fetchAll ( \PDO::FETCH_CLASS, $class, $ctorArgs );
```

With this code `$result` is empty.

When I paste in the binding value into the query manually and run it in phpMyAdmin, then I get two records back (which is what I expect):

```
SELECT * 
FROM payment
WHERE  `user_id` = 8
AND MONTH(pay_date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) 
ORDER BY `pay_date` DESC
```

And when I run the above PDO code WITHOUT the `MONTH(CURDATE())`, then PDO also returns records:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM payment WHERE  `user_id` = :userid_53e3d3275e364 ORDER BY `pay_date` DESC';
$bindings = array ( 'userid_53e3d3275e364' => 8 );

$stmt = $this->db->prepare ( $sql );
$stmt->execute ( $bindings );
$result = $stmt->fetchAll ( \PDO::FETCH_CLASS, $class, $ctorArgs );
```

But for some reason something, somewhere seems to go wrong when I put `MONTH(CURDATE())` as binding value.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: You can't bind an expression with a function call to a parameter. It will be "transmitted" as string. But there's no need to use a parameter for this expression. Use it simply in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

things like `CURDATE()` and `NOW()` must be present in the query, not in the values:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM payment WHERE  `user_id` = :userid_53e3d3275e364  AND  MONTH(CURDATE()) = :monthpaydate_53e3d3275e373  ORDER BY `pay_date` DESC';
```

The reason for that is quite logical: parameters are passed so that they do not need to be evaluated by mySQL (values being evaluated by mySQL is a big security issue - sql injection). So in fact, when your query is acually executed, it compares your field to the **characters** `"CURDATE()"` and not to the **result** of the function, which is what you want. But! We just have to put it in the query at the very start.

moreover, the way you bind params lacks the `:`

```
$bindings = array ( ':userid_53e3d3275e364' => 8, 
                    ':monthpaydate_53e3d3275e373' => 'MONTH(CURDATE())' );
```

But I must say I don't understand this `MONTH(CURDATE()) = :monthpaydate_53e3d3275e373`

you sure you do not mean `monthField = MONTH(CURDATE())` ??

I don't know your database schema, so monthField is actually you own column name

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
$bindings = array ( 'userid_53e3d3275e364' => 8, 
                    'monthpaydate_53e3d3275e373' => 'MONTH(CURDATE())' );
```

It doesn't work like that. PDO cannot bind mysql functions. It can only bind hard data.

You shouldn't be binding that. Instead put it in your query.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM payment WHERE  `user_id` = :userid_53e3d3275e364  AND  MONTH(pay_date) =  MONTH(CURDATE())  ORDER BY `pay_date` DESC';

$bindings = array ( ':userid_53e3d3275e364' => 8 );
```

P.S. Also what Félix Gagnon-Grenier said, you need the ":" in your params.